# Wha's a scalable way to query a rate limited API?

Tags: design-patterns, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

I need to build a service which makes REST calls to 3rd party service. The 3rd party service is rate limited for every minute, day and month. Once the data is fetched, it is stored in a data store. We need approximately 60,000 calls to fetch all the data required.

Currently, I have created a SQS which stores the Job information. And Lambda picks up the task and performs an API call to the service and stores it in the datastore.

When the lambda hits the rate limit ( 429 status code ), the SQS should stop sending messages. Or is there a better way to perform this ?

How do we handle for these rate limits ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have minute, day, and month rate limits, it means that the monthly limit is going to be lower than the other two, because otherwise it would be redundant.

This structure basically means that you have to be careful never to exceed the rate limits.  If you call up to the limit for a few consecutive minutes, then you'll exceed the daily limit and be blocked off for the rest of the day.  If you hit your daily limit for a few successive days, then you'll hit the monthly limit and be locked out for a *whole month*.

That's probably not what you want, so instead of waiting for and responding to 429s, you have to rate-limit your own calls, so that you basically never get 429s.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Step Functions supports [retries via custom "retriers"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#error-handling-retrying-after-an-error) that allow you to specify custom backoff periods and numbers of retries. Have you tried these?

The relevant [ASL](https://states-language.net/spec.html#errors) would look something like the following:

```
"X": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:task:X",
  "Next": "Y",
  "Retry": [
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [ "429" ],
      "IntervalSeconds": 1,
      "BackoffRate": 2,
      "MaxAttempts": 22
    }
  ],
  "Catch": [
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [ "States.ALL" ],
      "Next": "Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that this will backoff exponentially and retry for over one month.